# How to keep some numbers and delete other numbers in a SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, digits, amazon-athena

Let's say my data is like:

```
abcd abcd aaa 1234 1234566789 abcd abcd aaa 123456789 1234sfjsalfj
```

what I want to do is:

1. if a number is 3 to 6 digits and there is `aaa` in front of it, then I keep it.
2. I do not need other numbers if no aaa ahead, or the number of digits is out of my range `(3-6)`

So, this example should be transferred to:

```
abcd abcd aaa 1234 abcd abcd sfjsalfj
```

How to do this in Athena SQL? Maybe not a single query. Using with or any other query combination is also fine.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and regex support is quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: SQL is not well suited for complex string manipulations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this regex to do the replacement in one query:

```
(?<!aaa |\d)\d+\s*|(aaa (\d{1,2}(?!\d)|\d{7,})\s*)
```

This looks for any digits not preceded by `aaa` , or 1, 2, or >6 digits which are preceded by `aaa` . Any matches should be replaced by the empty string (using the two parameter version of `regexp_replace` i.e.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('abcd abcd aaa 1234 1234566789 abcd abcd aaa 123456789 1234sfjsalfj', '(?<!aaa |\d)\d+\s*|(aaa (\d{1,2}(?!\d)|\d{7,})\s*)')
```

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3oaxPG/1)